# Formula for gamma correction

Tags: image-processing

I'd like to do some image processing where gamma-correction is important. I've searched the web for the generic formula, but couldn't find one that fits my needs.

Comment: It's hard to give an answer that "fits your needs" when you haven't told us what those are specifically, or what's wrong with the answers you found.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pretty "generic" question as well. If you're not interested in a solution for a particular programming language, this formular is the one to go with:

```
g'(g) = w_max * ((g - w_min) / (w_max - w_min)) ^ gamma + w_min
```

w_max and w_min are the maximum and minimum intensity values in your image and g is the intensity value before gamme correction.

Comment: Gamma correction is sensitive to offsets, so adding and subtracting `w_min` will give the wrong results for most purposes unless `w_min` happens to be zero.

Comment: I would say it should be "(wmax - wmin) * pow( (g - wmin) / ( wmax - wmin), 1/gamma) + wmin" in order to get output values in range  wmin..wmax while pow values move from 0.0 to 1.0.

Answer (score 3):

After doing a quick Google search for gamma correction matlab (I used matlab for image processing in college), I came across this page (http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/5347-gamma-correction) and this code:

```
Err = 0;
if nargin < 2
    GammaValue = 1;
    disp('Default value for gamma = 1');
else if nargin ==2 & GammaValue < 0
     GammaValue = 1;
     disp('GammaValue < 0, Default value considered, Gammavalue = 1');
else if nargin > 2
     disp('Error : Too many input parameters');
     Err = 1;
end
if Err == 1 
x = imread(Image);
x = double(x);
Correction = 255 * (x/255).^ GammaValue; 
end;
```